# difficult query to Eloquent

Tags: sql, eloquent

We tried to convert that sql string to eloquent format but its not working. Please anybody help me

```
      SELECT [session_id]
      ,[creation_time]
      ,[device_id]
      ,[isEmailSent]
      ,[comment]
      ,[patient_id]
      ,[doctor_id]
  FROM [dbo].[tbl_session_protocol] t
  where t.doctor_id=10
  and  cast(t.creation_time as date) = (select cast(max(s.creation_time) as date) from tbl_session_protocol s where s.doctor_id=10);
```

Comment: how to write this query using eloquent?

Comment: sorry man, misread the question: I've deleted my comment

Comment: What query have you tried?